# JBoss AS 7.1 ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed:

Tags: java, eclipse, authentication, jboss

I have two projects, one si running on the server (JBoss AS 7.1) and the other one should by client, who can communicate with the server.

Both are on the same machine.

[Picture of my eclipse workspace](http://i58.tinypic.com/28hzi54.png)

Here is my code from class Main.java which is in client project.

```
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CalculetteService calculette = null;
        try {
            Context    context = new InitialContext();
            calculette = (CalculetteService) context.lookup("ejb:/Analyzator-Server//CalculetteServiceImpl!CalculetteService");
            System.out.println("Vysledok je: " + calculette.add(10, 10));
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public Main() {
        super();
    }

}
```

After trying to run it I get this error:

```
apr 29, 2015 4:26:12 PM org.xnio.Xnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
apr 29, 2015 4:26:12 PM org.xnio.nio.NioXnio <clinit>
INFO: XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
apr 29, 2015 4:26:12 PM org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl <clinit>
INFO: JBoss Remoting version 3.2.2.GA
apr 29, 2015 4:26:13 PM org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteConnection handleException
ERROR: JBREM000200: Remote connection failed: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(Unknown Source)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:87)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.cache.ConnectionCache.get(ConnectionCache.java:42)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.createConnection(InitialContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateConnection(InitialContextFactory.java:126)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:106)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: all available authentication mechanisms failed
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:365)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.remote.ClientConnectionOpenListener$Capabilities.handleEvent(ClientConnectionOpenListener.java:214)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel.handleReadable(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:189)
    at org.xnio.channels.TranslatingSuspendableChannel$1.handleEvent(TranslatingSuspendableChannel.java:103)
    at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:72)
    at org.xnio.nio.NioHandle.run(NioHandle.java:90)
    at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:184)
    at ...asynchronous invocation...(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:270)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.doConnect(EndpointImpl.java:251)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:349)
    at org.jboss.remoting3.EndpointImpl.connect(EndpointImpl.java:333)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.cache.EndpointCache$EndpointWrapper.connect(EndpointCache.java:110)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.cache.ConnectionCache.get(ConnectionCache.java:41)
    ... 8 more
```

I tried everything I was able to find on the internet but nothing helps.

Here is part of my standalone.xml, else is set to default

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9980}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

And my jndi.properties which are also in client project

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url = remote\://localhost\:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
```

Server is running fine, with no errors.

I would be very grateful for your help because I don't know what else to try. Thank you for your time.